# notepad not writing in C#

Tags: c#

I know I am missing something but unable to figure out. Target is to add the strings to notepad .

```
public static class PacketLog
    {
       public static TextWriter Str = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Titi.txt",true);

        public static void LogPacket(string Data)
        {

            Str.WriteLine(Data);
            Str.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

PacketLog.Logpacket("ABC");

Its not logging the string to the Notepad. where is the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by writing to notepad? are you trying to write to a text file, or just literally write to notepad?

Comment: .txt file. Its TXT file

Comment: Close notepad and open it again, to see the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the stream at some point. So you need a method for your implementation:

```
public static class PacketLog
{
   public static TextWriter Str = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Titi.txt",true);

    public static void LogPacket(string Data)
    {
        Str.WriteLine(Data);
        Str.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public static void CloseLog()
    {
        Str.Close();
    }
}
```

or use `using` statement which will call `Close` at the end.

```
public static void LogPacket(string Data)
{
    using(TextWriter Str = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Titi.txt",true))
    {
        Str.WriteLine(Data);
        Str.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes this was solution for it. I was not closing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write to text file like:

```
File.WriteAllText("D:\Titi.txt", content);
```

and to append new text (as you asked in comment), you can use:

```
File.AppendAllText("D:\Titi.txt", content);
```

and as Reniuz said, changes will not reflect in the notepad, untill you close and open the file again. because notepad is a very simple program, and it does no watch for changes outsite the application. howver if you use Noptepad++, if there is a change to a file, it prompts that if you want to load the new content.

**Edit:**
If you want to open the file to append several times. Note that `AppendAllText()` creates the file if it does not exist, so just using it is enough, and you don't need to check existance of the file to create it for the first time.

Comment: This erase the last value. Always keeps the latest string. Need to append every time with the old value.

Comment: @LokanathDas I edited my answer to fit your need, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not closing your TextWriter.

```
Str.Close();
```

add that and it will write your lines.

Comment: a `using` statement would be much better in this situation

Comment: I would've used `using` in my answer but he's asking what he's missing in his code. So I pointed out that code. He's probably new in c# in general and the best way to teach him is to give the basics. As they say, learn to walk before you run

Comment: you are absolutely right. But SO isn't just for the one who states the questions. It's also when you search for a known problem and find useful tips, might be in 2 years somebody comes here and sees this comment. I myself really like it if in the comments there are tips to improve myself, and not just give me an answer, that might be even bad... That's why it's a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: I didn't take your comment as an offense, I was about to edit my answer based from your comment but someone already placed a `using` answer after me. So I just stuck with my answer and cancelled my edit :p